Windows RDS Server with UPD files, start menu gone after relogin
I am currently setting up a RDS (Terminal Server) with Win 2022. Its configured to store the profiles on a share as UVHD (UPD) file in a network drive. Some folders like pictures I store on a network drive in an own folder.
However, when a user logs in fresh, everything looks fine.
When the user logs out and in again, the start menu is broken; nearly all apps and icons are missing.

I can delete the UVHD file and then reproduce the same scenario again.
Some folders like

AppData\Local
AppData\LocalLow
Pictures, etc

are excluded from UPD.
anyone knows what is the reason for that?

I figured out that the reason seems to be that

AppData\Local
AppData\LocalLow

are excluded from the UPD (VHDX files). And they can not be placed localy as the virtual disk takes the whole user home. In other words, they are then nowhere.
So it means the only way is to include them into the UPD, which is not good for performance reason.
Finally Microsoft bought Fslogix - a solution that is better than the built in UPD usage. So better forget the UPD settings in Server-Manager and setup Fslogix, which can be configured very detailed how to use folders on terminalservers for users.
